# How to achieve the functions of turned-page and continued-page

Tags: page-breaking, journal

I'm making a template for a journal. The editors would like to achieve the following functions:

When the page can not hold up the last part (maybe some **references** or **sections**) of an manuscript, the rest of this manuscript will be arranged at the end of another manuscript (after the references).

Noting that when typesetting the turned-page and continued-page, the page-numbers should be shown, and **the numbers of sections and references** should also be typesetted **continuously**.

The following is my codes. And in order to achieve these functions, I split the reference environment and input the rest of references manually. I will appreciate it if someone could provide some elegant codes and better ideas.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\PageTo#1{\bigskip\hfill{\bfseries(Turned to page #1)\par}}
\def\PageFrom#1{\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.3mm}%
                \par\noindent{\bfseries(Continued from page #1)\par}}
\begin{document}
  \title{This is an example}
  \author{Anyone}
  \maketitle
  \vskip-15pt
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{bm}  Bondy A., Murty R. Graph Theory with Applications.
        New York: Macmilan Ltd Press, 1976.
    \bibitem{bm}  Bondy A., Murty R. Graph Theory with Applications.
        New York: Macmilan Ltd Press, 1976.
    \bibitem{bm}  Bondy A., Murty R. Graph Theory with Applications.
        New York: Macmilan Ltd Press, 1976.
    \bibitem{bm}  Bondy A., Murty R. Graph Theory with Applications.
        New York: Macmilan Ltd Press, 1976.
    \bibitem{bm}  Bondy A., Murty R. Graph Theory with Applications.
        New York: Macmilan Ltd Press, 1976.
  \end{thebibliography}
    \PageTo{\pageref{page:comeback}}\label{page:leave}
  \lipsum[1-3]
    \PageFrom{\pageref{page:leave}}\label{page:comeback}

  \bigskip\noindent
  [6] Bondy A., Murty R. Graph Theory with Applications.
      New York: Macmilan Ltd Press, 1976.\bigskip

  \noindent
  [7] Bondy A., Murty R. Graph Theory with Applications.
      New York: Macmilan Ltd Press, 1976.
\end{document}
```

Here is a figure illustrating the wanted result.

[image]